# Sending message with custom URL though Geoloqi

Tags: ios, geolocation

I'm looking into Geoloqi as a service for sending messages and I'm wondering about the url parameter described here:

- https://developers.geoloqi.com/api/message/send

Can I use a custom protocol/URL scheme to launch my app in response to a sent message.

(I would assume yes, but need to be sure before progressing further with it).

Answer (score 0):

According to the web page you've linked, one of the parameters that can be sent along with the "`POST`" is a URL that can be opened when the notification is tapped.

It's here that I think you could put your custom URL.  No way to know if the server will accept a custom scheme (e.g. "`bradrobinson://hi/there`") though without trying.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question.  Messages sent to a phone through geoloqi are sent as push notifications and that url can be opened by the user.  If that url is a custom url scheme, will it launch my app - or will it only launch a browser.